# How do I use overloaded functions with default arguments in algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, default-arguments

I know the answer to the frequently-asked *[How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-to-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function)*: Either with assignment or with a cast, and every other C++ tutorial uppercases a string like this (give or take `static_cast`):

```
transform(in.begin(), in.end(), back_inserter(out), (int(*)(int)) std::toupper);
```

Or like this:

```
int (*fp)(int) = std::toupper;
transform(in.begin(), in.end(), back_inserter(out), fp);
```

Which neatly selects the `<cctype>` overload of `std::toupper`.

But this begs the question: How can I select the `<locale>` overload in a similar manner?

```
char (*fp2)(char, const std::locale&) = std::toupper;
transform(in.begin(), in.end(), back_inserter(out), fp2);
// error: too few arguments to function
```

Or, more practically, consider someone trying to use the C++11 `std::stoi` in an algorithm to convert a vector of strings to a vector of integers: `stoi` has two overloads (`string`/`wstring`), each taking two additional default arguments.

Assuming I don't want to [explicitly bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294261/tr1mem-fn-and-members-with-default-arguments/294283#294283) all those defaults, I believe it is impossible to do this without wrapping such call in an auxiliary function or lambda. Is there a boost wrapper or TMP magic to do it for me in completely generic manner? Can a wrapper like `call_as<char(char)>(fp2)` or, more likely, `call_as<int(const std::string&)>(std::stoi)` even be written?

Comment: Can you just use a lambda in your `transform` command? Easiest and cleanest.

Comment: I wrote and deleted a comment about `bind` already being the wrapper you were looking for.  Then it occurred to me that you'd have to provide the default values to bind, thus re-defining them.

Comment: It's better to get the algorithm right before thinking about how to obfuscate the code via template stuff. So, start with algorithm. `std::toupper` call yields Undefined Behavior if there is a negative argument except `EOF` value.

Comment: You can do `auto *x = std::toupper<char>;`. That looks considerably shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's funny, I was doing something similar. The best way I found to do it was using lambdas as follows, because otherwise, you have to use a typedef to get the right overload and a std::bind to get rid of the locale, or not use the locale. However, this works much more cleanly:

```
static const std::locale loc;
transform(in.begin(), in.end(), back_inserter(out), [&loc](char c) {
  return std::toupper(c, loc);
});
```

I use the static to save the effort of reallocating each time.

Or you could get a typedef and do:

```
 std::bind((LocaleCompare)std::toupper, std::placeholders::_1, loc); // UGLY!
```

Answer (score 0):

You could should create a typedef of that functon pointer type, and then cast the function.

```
typedef char (*LocaleToUpper)(char, const std::locale&) ;
char (*fp2)(char, const std::locale&) = (LocaleToUpper)toupper;
```